# PDO on MySQL query through String variables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this code for my school project in which my program should be able to reply automatically to queries which was sent to it using an open-source program.

I have succeeded on creating a simple auto-reply with it with the help of someone who is knowledgeable with it. However I'm struggling on getting values through PHP-MySQL with string variables.

```
$reqproduct = $db->query("SELECT Crop FROM crops WHERE Crop = '$product'");
$reqprice = $db->query("SELECT Price FROM crops WHERE Crop = '$product'");
```

And yes of course, I've failed horribly.

Then I tried to learn PHP:PDO but I still get stuck on how to use its commands even with the help of its documentation.

Here is an excerpt of what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php
    try{
    //test database connection
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gammu;','root'); 
    echo "Connected<p>";} 
    catch (Exception $e){echo "Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage() ."<p>";} 

    //get data from database through decoded message
        $product = 'Okra'; //sample decoded message

        $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT Crop FROM crops WHERE Crop = :product'); 
        $sth->execute(array(':product' => "{$product}"));
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        foreach ($result as $row) { $reqproduct = $row; break;}
        $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT Price FROM crops WHERE Crop = :product'); 
        $sth->execute(array(':product' => "{$product}"));
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        foreach ($result as $row) { $reqprice = $row; break;}

    //to be sent to the sender
        $message = "The price of $reqproduct is $reqprice/kilo." ;
        echo $message;
    $db = null;
?>
```

I would like to get the value of what's inside the $message, any help would be really appreciated.

Also, crops.sql contains 3 columns. Namely the 'ID', 'Crop', and 'Price'.

Comment: You should have in your pdo string a user and a password,I only see the user.

Comment: To help you understand the contents of `$row`, and `$result`, use `var_dump($result);` and `var_dump($row);`  The first is a 2D array containing the second.  So you need to retrieve your value `Crop` by its array index.  `$reqprice = $row['Crop'];`

Comment: Otherwise, your code is pretty good. I'd recommend using indentation instead of inline `{}` blocks in the control structures like `foreach`, and don't use `"{$product}"` when you just need the variable `$product`.

Comment: @Mihai : It still connects though, I did not alter the default pass of my phpmyadmin :)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : I will try your suggestion about the foreach. And also about the $product, I probably left it unedited before I challenged PHP:PDO. Will change it, thanks :)

Comment: @Mihai The password argument is optional. MySQL supports password-less connections

Comment: @Dahh According to Stack Overflow guidelines, please dont add 'solved' to the post title. Marking an answer as 'accepted' is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got another help again, here's the better code. :)

```
    $crop_query = $db->query("SELECT Crop, Price FROM crops WHERE Crop = '{$product}' ");
    $crop_query->execute(array(':product' => "{$product}"));
    $result = $crop_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //just fetch one row

    $message = "The price of {$result->Crop} is {$result->Price}/kilo";
```

Comment: Accept this answer to mark the question as solved; do this by clicking the outlined checkmark under the down arrow.  I'm editing your title as [solved] is not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a few things wrong here.

Firstly SQL can grap a few columns at once so it should go into one query like this:

`SELECT Crop, Price FROM crops WHERE Crop = 'product'`

Then, when you do mysql fetch you can get the value out of the row  like this:

```
$crop = $row['Crop'];
$price = $row['Price'];
```

Each column maps to an element in the array. To see what it looks like try:

`var_dump($row);` after you call fetchAll

See FETCH_ASSOC here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: Yes, my bad. I just copy-pasted the reqprice part when posting the question. Also the "WHERE Crop = 'product'" part will only query the string itself instead of the variable, which was also my problem before moving on PHP: PDO as expressed on the question.